# Me gustaria saber que esta mal en mi codigo

Tags: python-3.x

Deberás definir una función notas_alumnos(lista), la cual recibe una lista de listas en el siguiente formato. La función deberá retornar una lista de tuplas, donde cada tupla contiene el nombre de un estudiante y su nota final.
Esta lista puede contener distinta información y en distinto orden, pero siempre va a tener al menos el nombre y la nota final. la siguiente función debera dar como resultado:
[('Carlitos', 5.2), ('Valeria', 3.9), ('Jorge', 3.3), ('Carlitos', 2.8)]

```
lista = [['Altura (cm)', 'Color favorito', 'Nombre', 'Nota final'],
        [181, 'Azul', 'Carlitos', 5.2], 
        [143, 'Blanco', 'Valeria', 3.9], 
        [143, 'Morado', 'Jorge', 3.3], 
        [149, 'Rosa', 'Carlitos', 2.8]]
nombre = lista[0].index('Nombre')
nota = lista[0].index('Nota final')
lista = lista[1:]
def notas_alumnos(lista):
    lis_1 = []
    lis_2 = []
    for i in lista:
        lis_1.append(i[nombre])
        lis_1.append(i[nota])
        t = tuple(lis_1)
        lis_2.append(t)
        lis_1 = []
    return lis_2
print(notas_alumnos(lista))
```

Mi duda es la siguiente, este codigo da como resultado exactamente lo que me pide el ejercicio, pero la plataforma Coursera dice que entrega este reslultado:

[('Nota final', 'Nombre'), (3.6, 'Jorge'), (7.0, 'Valeria'), (4.2, 'Jorge'), (2.8, 'Carlitos')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra opción utilizando diccionarios y asumiendo que el diccionario tiene las mismas claves en todos los elementos.

```
def Notas_Alumnos(diccionario):
    nombre_key = 'Nombre'
    nota_key = 'Nota final'

    nombres = [diccionario[nombre_key] for diccionario in diccionario]
    notas_finales = [diccionario[nota_key] for diccionario in diccionario]

    notas_alumnos = list(zip(nombres, notas_finales))

    return notas_alumnos

diccionario = [
    {'Nombre': 'Carlitos', 'Nota final': 5.2},
    {'Nombre': 'Valeria', 'Nota final': 3.9},
    {'Nombre': 'Jorge', 'Nota final': 3.3},
]

notas_alumnos = Notas_Alumnos(diccionario)
print(notas_alumnos)
```

que se puede simplificar aún más utilizando una lista de compresión.

```
def Notas_Alumnos(diccionario):
    return [(alumno['Nombre'], alumno['Nota final']) for alumno in diccionario]

# Ejemplo de uso con un diccionario
diccionario = [
    {'Nombre': 'Carlitos', 'Nota final': 5.2},
    {'Nombre': 'Valeria', 'Nota final': 3.9},
    {'Nombre': 'Jorge', 'Nota final': 3.3},
]

notas_alumnos = Notas_Alumnos(diccionario)
print(notas_alumnos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo es correcto para ese ejemplo concreto de entrada, el problema es que este tipo de plataformas lo que suelen hacer es especificar el nombre de una función, clase, etc que debes definir obligatoriamente en tu script y que usan como punto de entrada para ejecutar una serie de test. Es decir, la forma de evaluar el ejercicio consiste en ejecutar tu función `notas_alumnos` pasandole distintas listas de entrada y evaluar si su salida coincide con la salida esperada para esa entrada.

Si importas tu script y ejecutas la función con una lista con diferente orden como es:

```
lista = [['Altura (cm)', 'Color favorito', 'Nota final', 'Nombre'],
        [143, 'Morado', 3.6, 'Jorge'], 
        [143, 'Blanco', 7.0, 'Valeria'], 
        [150, 'Rojo', 4.2, 'Jorge'], 
        [149, 'Rosa', 2.8, 'Carlitos',]]
```

obtienes exactamente la misma salida que Coursera te muestra. Esto se debe a que los indices que usa son los apropiados para tu lista ejemplo, pero no son los apropiados para otras listas de entrada.

Por tanto, **la función debe determinar el indice de `"Nombre"` y `"Nota final"` para cada lista de entrada**. El código a subir debería ser simplemente:

```
def notas_alumnos(lista):
    nombre = lista[0].index('Nombre')
    nota = lista[0].index('Nota final')
    lista = lista[1:]

    lis_1 = []
    lis_2 = []

    for i in lista:
        lis_1.append(i[nombre])
        lis_1.append(i[nota])
        t = tuple(lis_1)
        lis_2.append(t)
        lis_1 = []

    return lis_2
```

Por cierto, tu función se puede simplificar bastante, sin cambiar la lógica que aplicas. No es necesario que crees una segunda lista auxiliar y su posterior conversión a tupla:

```
def notas_alumnos(lista_alumnos):
    indice_nombre = lista_alumnos[0].index('Nombre')
    indice_nota = lista_alumnos[0].index('Nota final')
    salida = []
    
    for alumno in lista_alumnos[1:]:
        salida.append((alumno[indice_nombre], alumno[indice_nota]))
    return salida
```